# Problem Publishing an Array with Rosserial

Tags: python, arrays, arduino, ros

I'm using my arduino to publish a simple array. This is the code I'm using:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16MultiArray.h>
ros::NodeHandle  nh;
int value[2]={1,6};
std_msgs::Int16MultiArray str_msg;
ros::Publisher chatter("uno", &str_msg);
void setup()
{
nh.initNode();
nh.advertise(chatter);
}
void loop()
{
str_msg.data = value[2];
str_msg.data_length = 2;
chatter.publish( &str_msg );
nh.spinOnce();
delay(1000);
}
```

This code compiles on the Arduino but returns the following message:

```
warning: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'std_msgs::Int16MultiArray::_data_type* {aka int*}' [-fpermissive] str_msg.data = value[2];
```

Also, when I run echo on my Terminal I receive the wrong array. Something like this:

```
layout: 
dim: []
data_offset: 0
data: [30, 0]
```

How can I fix this? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Thanks to the help of Fruchtzwerg I found the mistake. The below code is the answer.

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16MultiArray.h>
ros::NodeHandle  nh;
int value[2]={1,6};
std_msgs::Int16MultiArray str_msg;
ros::Publisher chatter("uno", &str_msg);
void setup()
{
nh.initNode();
nh.advertise(chatter);
}
void loop()
{
str_msg.data = value;
str_msg.data_length = 2;
chatter.publish( &str_msg );
nh.spinOnce();
delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set the value of `str_msg.data` but it is an array and no single field. So you need to set an index here also:

```
str_msg.data[0] = value[0];
str_msg.data[1] = value[1];
```

If you have more fields in future, you can simply use a memcopy here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If I understood correctly I have to replace this: `str_msg.data = value[2];` with what you told me right?
By doing that the arduino code uploads correctly but when I run echo on my Terminal the array I get is [30,6]. The value 6 is the one I'm sending, but the 1 is being replaced by a 30.

Comment: I added an EDIT code in the original message. That is the new code I used

Comment: I found the mistake. Using str_msg.data = `value[2]` gave me an error so I changed it to `str_msg.data = value`. With this I'm getting the correct array. Thanks for your help!